# Regressing a column against itself

Tags: r, lm

Regressing a variable against itself should give a slope of 1.

I have a dataframe where I want to regress several columns (including a fixed column 'i') against the fixed column 'i'. 
The slope coefficients from each regression are needed for a plot. 
But the regression of col 'i' against itself gives no slope row in the summary.

```
a <- rnorm(100, 22,4)     # some data
b <- rnorm(100, 30,7)     # only to create a dataframe
df <- data.frame(cbind(a,b))
head(df)
summary(lm(data = df, a~a)) # regress a against itself

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  22.2602     0.3504   63.53   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Why is there no slope coefficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are using the same name for both the dependent and the independent variable. If you just copy `a` to the `b` variable, it works:

```
df <- data.frame(cbind(a,b=a))
summary(lm(data = df, a~b))

Call:
lm(formula = a ~ b, data = df)

Coefficients:
         (Intercept)                     b  
-0.00000000000001137   1.00000000000000044
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code generates 2 warnings, the second arises because of the first:

```
Warning messages:
1: In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
  the response appeared on the right-hand side and was dropped
2: In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
  problem with term 1 in model.matrix: no columns are assigned
```

So your column of interest is dropped from the formula and hence is no slope coefficient, just intercept.